# How do I add a picture as default bullet point in the list, that be chosen in Powerpoint?

Tags: image, powerpoint, bullet

I am trying to add a default bullet point to the list. the bullet point is a picture - see attached

At the moment, everytime we want to add our picture (personalised) bullet point into a slide, we have to:
choose "bullets and numbering
Picture - then add the picture.

its a very time consuming process, when updating presentations that needs the changes.
OR
we can copy and paste the personalised bullet point with a letter where we want to start a new list.

Is is possible to have our personalised bullet point (which is a picture) remain in the list of bullets to choose from.

I have tried to change it in slide master, but it does not work.

Comment: As a test (in Windows PPT 2021) I went into Slide Master view, chose the Title & Content layout and set the bullet formatting for the first two levels to icons. Pictures should work identically. Then back in Normal view, I created a slide based on that layout, added text at various bullet levels. The bullet formatting followed what I'd set in the slide master.
What did you try in Master view, and what version of Office are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your response Steve, 
Yes, it works in a new PPT. But we are trying to add it to an existing PP, so we can change the existing bullet points to our “picture”.
I changed it in the Master Slide on all slides.
If I insert a new page and choose the outline, it also works. 
The Version of Office, is Microsft 365
Could it be because I am using a PPT that was created in 2014? 
is there by any chance a way to have my bullet point included in the bullet point drop down all the time? In every PPT?

Comment: After changing the master/layouts you'll probably need to re-apply them to all of the slides that depend on the newly changed layouts.  Home tab | Slides group | apply the appropriate layout again.